# Split a string into valid words

Tags: python, algorithm, programming-challenge, strings, memory-optimization

I am trying to solve [this LeetCode question](https://leetcode.com/problems/word-break-ii/):

> Given a non-empty string s and a dictionary wordDict containing a list
>   of non-empty words, add spaces in s to construct a sentence where each
>   word is a valid dictionary word. Return all such possible sentences.
>
> Note:
>
> The same word in the dictionary may be reused multiple times in the
>   segmentation. You may assume the dictionary does not contain duplicate
>   words.

I have a solution that works correctly but exceeds python's memory limit on large inputs.

Note that the `Solution` class is required by LeetCode's interface.

```
from collections import defaultdict
class Solution:
    def wordBreak(self, s, wordDict):
        cache = defaultdict(list)
        word_dict = set(wordDict)
        def partition(s):
            if s in cache:
                return cache[s]
            res = []
            if s in word_dict:
                res.append(s)
            for i in range(1, len(s)):
                words = partition(s[i:])
                k = s[:i]
                if k in word_dict:
                    for word in words:
                        res.append(k +" "+word)

            cache[s] = res 
            return res 
        return partition(s)
```

How do I optimize it in terms of space complexity?

Please refrain from commenting that the function doesn't have to be a method bound to the class instance. It cannot be changed as it is the template used to run the solution.

Comment: I'm afraid, this is not a working solution, when run, it produces an error 'NameError: name 'List' is not defined' either you fix the errors and present a properly running code or move it to StackOverflow. I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: @bullseye This might have been a copy paste error since the only error is missing the import statement. I edited the question, but anyone let me know if this change deviates from the authors intent (in my opinion it doesn't) and the edit will be rolled back accordingly.

Comment: Still it doesn't work due to the class Solution thing. And I think it's not allowed(my best guess, I don't know) to edit the code if it's not working, however let's wait and see.

Comment: @bullseye: It is allowed (and in fact, expected) to update the question with working code. What you must not do is to modify the code *after answers have been posted.*

Comment: @MartinR And when to flag the question as not-working?

Comment: @bullseye it works now. And what do you mean "Still it doesn't work due to the class Solution thing"? To use it, you need to instantiate  `Solution`, then call the relevant method.

Comment: @bullseye: My comment was only addressed to your remark that *“it's not allowed ... to edit the code if it's not working”*  which is wrong. Of course you are free to flag the question if you think that it is not working. – In this case however the code *is* (allegedly) working in the context of LeetCode, so that would (in my opinion) count as “working to the best knowledge of the author.”

Comment: @nz_21: I understand what you mean. However, as a *convenience* to the possible reviewers, you could add the necessary imports and a (minimal) main program to make the code runnable on its own.

Comment: @bullseye: I don't think that a missing import makes the question off-topic (in particular if OP states that it works as a LeetCode submission). Related on Meta: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2535/35991: “Code works when it does that which was intended in full and nothing more, ...” and https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1923/35991: “I don't believe that it is reasonable to require a question to include the entire codebase.”

Comment: @Martin R I understand that this code might be doing what it was intended to do. What is annoying here is the fact that to test this code, one has to remove this stupid class Solution template and run it in the IDE. I think this Leetcode website has a terrible design flaw plus it's very far from reality since when you're handling a real programming task you won't be given templates to fill, my opinion here is it blocks creativity and I think it shouldn't be accepted as review material on code review (and this is totally my opinion, not a fact).

Comment: @bullseye: I get your point (and you are free to [review the challenge requirements](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9345/35991)), but I don't agree that it makes the question itself off-topic (my opinion :)

Comment: And I get your point as well however since most people presenting such challenges are here for reviewing their coding abilities and not their challenge solving abilities again my opinion here is this should be considered as an off-topic specially such challenges force bad unrealistic code patterns.

Comment: @bullseye  "one has to remove this stupid class Solution template and run it in the IDE"  Uh... `s = Solution(); s.wordBreak(...)` -- are you seriously telling me that typing out a few extra characters requires you to bring out a full-fledged IDE to run the code?

Comment: @nz_21: This might interest you: [Determine all ways a string can be split into valid words, given a dictionary of all words](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/197558/35991).

Comment: @nz_21 are there other ways that i don't know of for running a code?

Comment: @bullseye yeah, google virtual environment. When you run it as is, presumably you're going to be running it against your system-wide python interpreter. A virtual env allows you to run the code against a specific python version.